# Replace input field error message text based on input field label name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, yii

So I have this account creation form for a company. Here's what it looks like:
[image]

I am going to explain first how a feature in this system works.

1. After company creation, a table will be shown, listing all the companies I created.
2. In the Action column of this table, there's an action button that once I click it, I will be logged in into a specific company I chose, acting as the user logged inside that company.
3. Inside, there's more like the same layout and I can create a sub-company called "Operator".
4. So there's a "Create Operator" button and once clicked, I will be redirected to the same form layout above (except that the "Company Name" label is changed to "Operator Name").
5. Alright, so I am using **Yii2 php framework** and basically, each input field is an attribute in a db table and in my model, there's a function called `public function attributeLabels()` where each of these attributes are assigned to a specific label.
6. For **example**, first input field's db table attribute name is `company_name` so inside this function it is assigned as `company_name => "Company Name"` and this label is passed to the view which is this form. So whenever there are error messages, this label is used.
7. Regardless if I am creating a company or operator, the error message is **always** "Company Name should not be blank". What I need to accomplish is when I create an operator, the error message should be "Operator Name should not be blank."

I hope you get my problem. So I tweaked some **javascript/jQuery** but I am still having problems.

```
// For changing Operator Name error message            
var operatorNameLabel = $('.field-company-company_name label').attr('for','company-company_name').text();
var companyNameErrorDiv = $(".field-company-company_name p");
var operatorNameMsg = 'Operator Name should not be blank.';

$('#submit-button').click(function() {
    // Change Operator Name error message
    if (operatorNameLabel == "Operator Name") {
        companyNameErrorDiv.html("<p class='help-block help-block-error'>Operator Name should not be blank</p>");
        //companyNameErrorDiv.text(operatorNameMsg);
    }
});

$('#content-offset').click(function () { 
    if (operatorNameLabel == "Operator Name") {
        companyNameErrorDiv.html("<p class='help-block help-block-error'>Operator Name should not be blank</p>");
        //companyNameErrorDiv.text(operatorNameMsg);
    }
});
```

My problem in my current code is that :

1. when I leave the operator name input field blank then click into a blank space outside the input field, the error message is still "Company Name should not be blank."
2. but then when I click back to the input field, that's the time the error message changes to "Operator Name should not be blank."
3. What really happens is that when I click at the operator name input field, then *single* click outside or at any other input fields, the error message remains "Company Name should not be blank.",
4. but when I do a *second* click, the the error message changes.
5. There's a problem when I click back to the operator name input field for it keeps on getting back to the "Company Name should not be blank" error message, when clicked.

I hope you get my problem.

EDIT:
Yii2 generated html looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group field-company-company_name required has-error">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label name-label" for="company-company_name" data-name="Operator Name">Operator Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" id="company-company_name" class="form-control" name="Company[company_name]" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <p class="help-block help-block-error">Company Name cannot be blank.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `required` attribute to `input` element, `data-*` at `label` element; `css` `:invalid`, `:after` pseudo element, `content` property of `label` to display message when `input` is invalid.

```css
input:invalid + label:after {
  content: " " attr(data-name) " should not be blank";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="company_name" required /><label data-name="Company Name"></label><br>
<input type="text" name="login_name" required /><label data-name="Login Name"></label><br>
<input type="email" name="email" required /><label data-name="Email"></label><br>
<input type="password" name="password" required /><label data-name="Password"></label><br>
<input type="password" name="password_confirm" required /><label data-name="Password Confirm"></label>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but not working, maybe because my `label` element comes before `input` element. Does that matter?

Comment: Yes, try with `<input>` element preceding `<label>` element, see [Adjacent Sibling Selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

Comment: I cannot alter the arrangement since the form is generated by Yii automatically. Here's what it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/w87RLtH.png

Comment: Can you include generated `html` at Question ?

Comment: _"I cannot alter the arrangement since the form is generated by Yii automatically."_ jQuery at Question alters arrangement by setting `.html()` at `".field-company-company_name p"` element ? Though, note, `".field-company-company_name p"` selects `p` element, then appends a a `p` child element to original selector at `companyNameErrorDiv.html("<p class='help-block help-block-error'>Operator Name should not be blank</p>")` ?

Comment: If it possible to use jQuery to append a `p` element to the generated `html`, it should be possible to append a `<label>` element as next sibling of `input` element; set `.help-block` and originally generated `label[for="company-company_name"]` to `display:none;` ; you should then be able to utilize `css` approach at post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107698/discussion-between-ethelene-laverne-and-guest271314).